# The argument Type 'Color' can't be assigned to the parameter type MaterialStateProperty<Color?>?

Tags: flutter, dart, checkbox

Hello I am trying to create a custom Checkbox widget to support dark and light themes in app. For that I am trying as below:

```
   static final CheckboxThemeData primaryLight =CheckboxThemeData(
    fillColor:AppColor.primary 
  );
```

But At the line `AppColor.primary`, its giving me compile time error as

> "The argument Type 'Color' can't be assigned to the parameter type
> MaterialStateProperty<Color?>?"

What might be the issue? Or How can I resolve this to make the common custom Checkbox for two different themes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
static final CheckboxThemeData primaryLight =CheckboxThemeData(
    fillColor:MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(AppColor.primary), 
);
```

Comment: Thanks Arijeet (not Singh), Its working.

Answer (score 1):

try this instead

```
static final CheckboxThemeData primaryLight =CheckboxThemeData(
fillColor:MaterialStateProperty.all(AppColor.primary ));
```